# Resolve continuous computer freezing with Nvidia RTX 2080 and "Nvidia Studio Driver"

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am experiencing continuous computer freezes when using Resolve. Normally it happens when I am playing the video or moving the cursor over the timeline, and the computer stops working - it is not a crash, it freezes the whole computer, so I hear the uncomfortable robotic sound of the video stuck, playing the same millisecond.

I have upgraded to the latest v`18.1.4` and I have upgraded my `Nvidia Studio Driver` but the problem is still there. It makes editing very tedious, as at any time my computer might freeze and I have to reset it to start again, sometimes losing work progress.

My computer is not bad to not be able to cope with the load of the videos. I have M.2 drives, 32 GB RAM and a Nvidia RTX 2080. And the error seems to happen even with a few videos, nothing really demanding.

I am getting out of options for a solution.

---

I assume this is unrelated, but when I start Resolve, I often see this screen:
[image: GPU Configuration Reset]

Then I have to go to the menu option:

[image: Menu]

Change it:

[image: Menu2]

And then close and start again Resolve.

This time works. But the next time I use it, Resolve complains again of the very same thing. Like if it was not able to save the configuration.